# Is there anyway to set referrer to like cloaking when checking?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-redirect

Currently, I using WordPress and already create link cloaking with Pretty Link plugin in pattern `example.com/get/link-1` for using on post URL `example.com/link-1/`.

However, is it possible that I will send directly `example.com/get/link-1` for visitor. But I need to make me or anyone that need to check path of `example.com/get/link-1` seen as sending path from `example.com/link-1/` before.

Comment: The HTTP `Referer` is set by the _browser_. So unless you implement a reverse proxy (that is able to inject/override this header) then this is not possible. However, I'm wondering why you would need to do this in the first place?

Comment: Thank you. I need to split test my stat.